# Impl for type with parameter that can be From<&'a str> and FromStr

Tags: rust

Consider following piece of rust code:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::convert::From;

trait Bar {
    fn baz();
}

struct Foo<A> {
    v: A
}

impl<A: FromStr> Bar for Foo<A> {   
    fn baz() {
        todo!()
        // code that somewhat handles conversion error possibly generated by parse()
    }
}

impl<'a, A: From<&'a str>> Bar for Foo<A> {
    fn baz() {
        todo!()
        // code that doesn't have to worry about conversion errors, since from() cannot fail
    }
}
```

It produces error about conflicting declarations. Namely:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Bar` for type `Foo<_>`
  --> src/lib.rs:19:1
   |
12 | impl<A: FromStr> Bar for Foo<A> {
   | ------------------------------- first implementation here
...
19 | impl<'a, A: From<&'a str>> Bar for Foo<A> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Foo<_>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

What I want to do is described in comments. For `A`s that can be created from `&str` without error I want different behaviour than for ones that require error handling. But somewhat `rustc` considers these declarations conflicting. Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for in current rust? If so, how?

[link to playground with above code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=02010f4fe39aa78ac5c8746798411ac0)

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate the code? Have only the version with error handling.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That was my initial idea but some types in standard library don't implement `FromStr` even though they do implement `From<&str>` (like `Vec<u8>`). This forces me to have different `impl` blocks with different generics bounds

Comment: If that's the problem, then no, there is no solution. You can use a newtype that converts between `From` and `FromStr`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman sounds like an answer to me

Comment: Could you explain your use case in a bit more detail? Why do you want to support both `From<&str>` and `FromStr`? These to traits server very different purposes.